# Terraform provider customization per different workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I would like to use terraform for prod/dev split. However, when it's development, we prefer to use the Local DynamoDB because of delay and cost. Created a sample .tf file as follows:

```
variable "workspace" {
  default = {
    local = "aws.local"
    prod = "aws.prod"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "prod"
  region = "us-west-2"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "local"
  access_key = "mock_access_key"
  region = "us-east-1"
  s3_force_path_style = true
  secret_key = "mock_secret_key"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check = true
  skip_requesting_account_id = true
  endpoints {
    dynamodb = "http://localhost:4000"
  }
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "terraform_queue" {
  provider = var.workspace[terraform.workspace]
  name = "terraform-example-queue"
}
```

Don't mind the SQS, using it as it's the simplest one. However when I try do `terraform init/plan`:

```
Error: Invalid provider configuration reference

  on deneme.tf line 28, in resource "aws_sqs_queue" "terraform_queue":
  28:   provider = var.workspace[terraform.workspace]

The provider argument requires a provider type name, optionally followed by a
period and then a configuration alias.
```

It looks like it needs provider to be an exact value, not an expression/interpolation, why Terraform is unable to deduce parametric configuration for provider? How does one achieve such split and handle seperation per workspace? I confirm my `terraform workspace show` returns `local`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar, what I ended up with was a single aws provider, configured dynamically using variables.

```
variable dynamodb_endpoint {
  type = string
  default = null
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-2"

  endpoints {
    dynamodb = var.dynamodb_endpoint
  }
}
```

During development I would then run with

```
terraform apply -var dynamodb_endpoint=http://localhost:9001
```

In production I didn't specify dynamodb_endpoint at all

```
terraform apply
```

In my setup the variables were overriden from the command line, but you could (and probably should) alter them based on the curent workspace.